# Open GL ES 2, matrix OrthoM and translation

Tags: opengl-es, rotation, translation

I have a problem with my translation and rotation .
When i want rotate like this it work
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyeOn.png

```
 textureProgram.useProgram();

for ( i =0; i < 5; i ++)
{
     Matrix.setLookAtM(modelMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
     Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
     Matrix.setRotateM(RotationMatrix, 0, 12f, 0, 0,  1.0f);
     Matrix.multiplyMM( projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0,    RotationMatrix,     0);   
    textureProgram.setUniforms(projectionMatrix, mur1texture);
     this.bindData(textureProgram);
     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
     }
```

But i can't rotate more than my far number in my OrthoM projection i dont understand at all.
For instance if my number is 3 like this one:

```
     Matrix.orthoM(projectionMatrix, 0, 0, 1280, 800, 0, -1, 3);
```

i will be able to rotate it 3 times not more even if i have to rotate 5 times.
I have to increase the number to be able to rotate it 5 times for example.
Can someone help me please , i don't really understand the problem.

EDIT : with this, it rotate just one time and the object get distortion when it rotate .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEfID.png

```
      for ( i =0; i < 5; i ++)
    {
    Matrix.setLookAtM(modelMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.setRotateM(RotationMatrix, 0, 12f, 0, 0,  1.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0, RotationMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);

     textureProgram.setUniforms(modelViewProjectionMatrix, mur1texture);
     this.bindData(textureProgram);
     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);

}
```

EDIT 2:
This way it rotate normally but just once :S .

```
  for ( i =0; i < 5; i ++)
   {
     Matrix.setLookAtM(modelMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
     Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
     Matrix.setRotateM(RotationMatrix, 0, 45f, 0, 0,  1.0f);
     Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0,  projectionMatrix, 0,       RotationMatrix, 0);


     textureProgram.setUniforms(modelViewProjectionMatrix, mur1texture);
     this.bindData(textureProgram);
     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);


}
```

Edit 3 : Still rotate only one time .

```
int u , i ;
textureProgram.useProgram();

Matrix.setLookAtM(modelmatrix, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelmatrix, 0);

 for ( i =0; i < 5; i ++)
 {

      Matrix.setRotateM(RotationMatrix, 0, 12f, 0, 0,  1.0f);
      Matrix.multiplyMM( modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0,RotationMatrix,     0);   
     textureProgram.setUniforms(modelViewProjectionMatrix, mur1texture);
     this.bindData(textureProgram);
     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
    }
```

Comment: easily explanation: before rotation you had some translate and did not translate back. In ortho projection you can't see how is your object moved far away from camera. something like that.

Comment: But in this example i didnt use gl translate so how can my object translate in z , i mean with what method ? cause in my on drawframes i just get  glClear and matrix.orthom method before rendering , so i dont know how it translate . If i know this i can try to translate back . Thanks you for helping me again SAKrisT .

Comment: it was mine apologies. 
in this line you have something strange Matrix.multiplyMM( projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, RotationMatrix,     0);

Comment: try with this code http://pastebin.com/Le3ncs1y

Comment: I come to try with your code but it seem to rotate just one time and get weird distortions , i edit the question this way you can see whats happen. I added pictures .

Comment: if you want rotate 5 times, put Matrix.setLookAtM outside cycle. Because each time you reseting camera position with this line. Or you need like that?

Comment: i did put it out of the cycle it continue rotate just one time :S . See my edit.

Comment: I meant http://pastebin.com/DbwGNnuL

Comment: It works , thanks  SAKrisT , you are the man. Always there when needed. Thanks you again.

Comment: You can vote for my comments, for upping my rating. I will vote your first question. Because if you want to have a chat with some one, then you need more reputation.

Comment: For moment i can't vote i need 15 point of reputation it seem , when i'll get them you can count on me.